# fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries in GMB API

Tags: python

```
# Execute the request and print the result
accounts_result = request.execute()
# print("accounts_result:")
account_resource_name = accounts_result['accounts'][1]['name']
# print("account_resource_name:")
print(account_resource_name)

fields_we_want = 'storeCode,name'

# Build the request to accounts.locations using list method
request = MyBusinessInformation.accounts().locations().list(
    parent=account_resource_name,
    readMask=fields_we_want,pageSize=40
    )

# Define the start and end dates
# start_date = datetime.date(2023, 4, 20)
# end_date = datetime.date(2023, 4,21)

# Execute the request and print the result
locations_result = request.execute()
#         print("locations_result:")
#         print(locations_result)



# body = MyBusinessPerfo.locations().fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries(location='locations/17872907566358893987', 
daily_metrics = ['WEBSITE_CLICKS', 'CALL_CLICKS']
start_date = {'year': 2023, 'month': 5, 'day': 1}
end_date = {'year': 2023, 'month': 5, 'day': 30}
daily_range = {'start_date': start_date, 'end_date': end_date}
response = MyBusinessPerfo.locations().fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries(
    location='locations/178xxxxxx6358893987',
    dailyMetrics=daily_metrics,
    dailyRange=daily_range
).execute()
print(response)
```

So I have tried multiple ways to pass the arguments correctly by referring to the document but failed. This is the error `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument dailyRange`

[Documentation link](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries#MultiDailyMetricTimeSeries)

```
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument dailyRange
```

need to get multiple metrics

Answer (score 0):

I see you are fetching MultiDailyMetrics but in your request you have provided only one metric, however your error message is telling about the dailyRange. Please have a look at [Date Object Documentation in BusinessProfilePerformance](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/Date).I code in  `JAVA` and I should set the dates as below:

Supposing that **metricsList** is defined as metrics which are interested to  you, and **business_profile_performance** is a variable of type `BusinessProfilePerformance` takes care of authentication and initialises the API:

```
final static List<String> metricsList=Arrays.asList("BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_MAPS",sum
            "BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_MAPS",  
            "BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_SEARCH",  
            "BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_SEARCH",  
            "BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS",  
            "CALL_CLICKS",      
            "WEBSITE_CLICKS"  
            );

 BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.FetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries request=business_profile_performance.locations()
                                        .fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries( my_locationName).setDailyMetrics(metricsList)
                                        .setDailyRangeStartDateYear(my_startYear)
                                        .setDailyRangeStartDateMonth(my_startMonth)
                                        .setDailyRangeStartDateDay(my_startDay)
                                        .setDailyRangeEndDateYear(my_endYear)
                                        .setDailyRangeEndDateMonth(my_endMonth)
                                        .setDailyRangeEndDateDay(my_endDay);

                        FetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse response = request.execute();
```

Comment: It should be the matter of syntax in python, try adding square brackets around your daily_range variable like this:  daily_metrics = [‘WEBSITE_CLICKS’, ‘CALL_CLICKS’] start_date = {‘year’: 2023, ‘month’: 5, ‘day’: 1} end_date = {‘year’: 2023, ‘month’: 5, ‘day’: 30} daily_range = {‘start_date’: start_date, ‘end_date’: end_date} response = MyBusinessPerfo.locations().fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries( location=‘locations/178xxxxxx6358893987’, dailyMetrics=daily_metrics, dailyRange=[daily_range]).execute()